# ui-router can't change value from $scope after view was called

Tags: angularjs, scope, controller

I'm starting using angularjs for my new websites, so I'm a beginner.
I have a problem, which I can't change the value from my $scope inside my controller after the view was called.
I'm using ui-router to multiple views.
I explain in this example:

```
<html lang="pt" ng-app="myApp">{...}
<header ng-controller="siteHeader"><div ng-show="mySlogan"></div></header><div ui-view="content"></div>
```

In my js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']); app.config(['$locationProvider','$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider'
,function($locationProvider,$stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

$stateProvider
    .state('home',{
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'content':{
                templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
                controller: 'siteHeader'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('login',{
        url: '/login',
        views: {
            'content':{
                templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
                controller: 'siteHeader'
            }
        }
    });}]);

app.controller('siteHeader',['$scope','$location',function($scope, $location){

if($location.path()=="/")
    $scope.mySlogan = true;
else
    $scope.mySlogan = false;}]);
```

The controller works at first time as page is load, but when the path was changed my $scope.mySlogan does nothing.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: why you create the same controller in '/login' and '/'

Comment: Controllers aren't singleton: you have an instance per view, when you change the view the controller is destroyed

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$state` service instead of `$location` and get the URL as following :

```
$state.url
```

Then, try to create a dedicated controller for each route. This will avoid using extensively conditions just to match specific route's template requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The code is only executed once in your controller assigned to `<header>`. The controllers assigned to your views are just other instances of `siteHeader` controller and define a new `mySlogan` variable in their own scope. So, changing the value there won't affect the value in the header scope.

To solve your problem, you could watch the location path:

```js
$scope.$watch(
  function() {
    return $location.path();
  }, function (newValue) {
    if (newValue === '/')
      $scope.mySlogan = true;
    else
      $scope.mySlogan = false;
  });
```

Or a better way would be to listen to the ui-router events:

```js
app.controller('siteHeader',['$scope',
  function($scope){

    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
      function(event, toState) {
        if ( toState.includes('home') )
          $scope.mySlogan = true;
        else
          $scope.mySlogan = false;
      });

  }]);
```

You need to assign the controller only to your sideHeader and not to your actual views.